# Only structured queries are supported FIRESTORE API REST

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run a query with the rest api but I can´t get it to work, I am sending this body in json:

```
"structuredQuery": {
     "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "total"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
                "integerValue": "10",
            }
         }
     }, 
     "from": [{
        "collectionId": "Total"
     }]              
}
```

I am just testing if querys work, I have a collection called Total with documents, and these documents have a field called total that is an integer value. I am using a POST request with the following URL:

```
"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery"
```

and I am getting this error:

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "only structured queries are supported",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CollectionSelector` in your structured query is missing the `allDescendants` field.

If you check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery#CollectionSelector) you can see that this field is a flag which can either be `true` or `false` but not `null`, so you have to set this in the query otherwise it will not work.

Also you need to add the `select` clause to add all fields you want to get as a result of the query or keep it empty to return all fields.

Finally in the said documentation you can check that there is a proper order that should be respected, in which the `from` must be declared before `where`. So if you change your structured query to the following:

```
"structuredQuery": {
    "from": [{
        "collectionId": "Total"
        "allDescendants": false
     }],
     "select": { "fields": [] }, 
     "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "total"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
                "integerValue": "10",
            }
         }
     }       
}
```

It will work as expected.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor It worked but with a select, I asked to the firestore team, and they replied that is because the select must go in the query

Comment: @MartinPellicer That is indeed correct, I have edited that into the answer.